# Why am I getting this error on live deployment but not on localhost? SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

My app is working in the localhost but recieving the following error on the live deployemnt.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON

So I'm assuming it's got to do with the fetch request on handleSubmit. The site is deployed to firebase. Do I need to setup some type of api domain that can handle these requests.

Error is being produced by line 31, on the catch.

Upon entering a term to translate, below the submit button the translation should occur. Which it does when I'm using  http://localhost:3000 on my pc. I changed that to the domain, though not sure what else needs to be done.

Newbie to all of this.

APP.JS

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');
   const [language, setLanguage] = useState('');

  // const cheerio = require('cheerio');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
   setMessage(e.target.value);
  }
  const handleLanguageChange = (e) => {
    setLanguage(e.target.value);
  }


  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('https://translatebrain.com/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message })
      
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setResponse(data.message))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>TranslateBrain</h1>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h2>Type text below</h2>
      <textarea value={message} onChange={handleChange} />
      <h2>Tranlate to</h2>
      <select value={language} onChange={handleLanguageChange}>
        <option value="English">English</option>
        <option value="French">French</option>
        <option value="German">German</option>
        <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
        <option value="Italian">Italian</option>
      </select>
      <h2>Click submit</h2>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <p>{response}</p>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

INDEX.JS

```
const OpenAI = require('openai')
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = OpenAI;

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3001;

const configuration = new Configuration({
    organization: "REDACTED",
    apiKey: "REDACTED",
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const { message , language } = req.body;
const response = await openai.createCompletion({
  model: "text-davinci-003",
  prompt: "Translate this into" + language + ":" + message,
  max_tokens: 100,
  temperature: 0,
});
console.log(response.data)
if(response.data.choices[0].text){
    res.send({message: response.data.choices[0].text})
}
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
    }
);
```

Spent hours trying to read how to overcome this issue,  but it's quite a lot to take in as a newbie. Managed to create a private key in firebase, but not sure how to link it all up.

Comment: What line of code causes the problem, and what are you expecting it to do differently?  Please edit the question to show your debugging details and we can use to reproduce the problem ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

try this, when you have:

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
```

add this:

```
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'      
'Accept':'application/json'
```

},

this is gona "force" to recieve data as json.

If not works, try to console.log all the response and post it again.
maybe there's another error 500 ?404? .. etc we neet to know